# Anyone can help me understand the meaning of “the grind is not glamorous”？

Tags: meaning

I heard "the grind is not glamorous" in the context of a video:

> If there is one thing I know about dreams, it's that to achieve them, you have to stop at nothing. So I spent ten years chasing it down. So I spent ten years chasing it down, and I said yes to every opportunity that involved picking up a camera: bar mitzvah videos, wedding videos, birthday videos. *The grind is not glamorous.* [—*[FILMMAKING IS A SPORT](https://youtu.be/2Dpd_8n3A5U)* (Context starts @ [1:33](https://youtu.be/2Dpd_8n3A5U?t=1m33s); phrase @ [1:49](https://youtu.be/2Dpd_8n3A5U?t=1m33s)) by Casey Neistat]

I have difficulty understanding it, but when I read [the entry for [grind]](https://www.tfd.com/grind) in *Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary* (©2010) on The Free Dictionary by Farlex, this helps it to make more sense:

> **17.** laborious, usu. uninteresting work.

Casey said filmmaking was his dream, and continues on to say "but I would not and I could not give up" after the provided excerpt, so I guess "the grind is not glamorous" might mean that the types of videos he was making, such as birthday or wedding videos, were "uninteresting", because his dream was to make movies that would be played at a movie theater.

Is that what he wants to express by using "the grind is not glamorous"?

Comment: I agree with @Tonepoet in that the OP must understand two idiomatic expressions here, not one.  A "grind" is a fairly nuanced idiom. - jumping to the monotous process of a labor and even a figurative suggestion of it's necessity doesn't appear in all definitions of the word.  "is not glamorous" means more figuratively than merely a statement of fact, although probably easy enough to grasp it's connotations on it's own. "Washing dishes is not glamorous work" says more than merely noting the absence of glamour.